# How to find an element inside a json response and then set a variable based on another element's content inside that object?

Tags: json, postman

This should be simple.

I am getting a json response in POSTMAN and need to search through it, and if I find an name in there, set an variable based on the id # of the object that contained that name :)

{ "jsonrpc": "2.0","result":[{"id": 396,"name": "LAB",},{         "id": 404,"name":"Networks",}],"id": 1}
         etc...

```
     So, if I need to find out the id of LAB, how to go about it?
```

Comment: can we have full length of json object?

Comment: never mind, i got it, and fix it, have a look in answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go:

its simple: iterate the json object and check if name is lab then print id

```
var x = { "jsonrpc": "2.0","result":[{"id": 396,"name": "LAB",},{ "id": 404,"name":"Networks",}],"id": 1} 

x.result.forEach(function(value, index){ 
    if(value["name"] == "LAB"){ 
        console.log(value["id"]);
    } 
  })
```

result is:

```
396
```